# Xamarin.forms iOS close current page when navigate to another page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a xamarin.forms app which have a navigation like this.

```
MainPage -->(PushmodelASync) Second Page-->(PushModelAsync)--> Third page
```

What I am trying to do is when navigating from `Second Page` to `Third Page` I need to Popmodelasync the second page. To do this I called PopmodelAsync in `OnDissappearing`. In android it works fine . But in iOS what happens is the third page will open and close instead of closing of second page

```
  protected async override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();           
        await Navigation.PopModalAsync();            
    }
```

How to solve this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I have updated an asnwer, you can have a look. If there are doubts can comment below. The reason is that iOS using model navigation will miss the instance of PageSecond in the `OnDisappearing` method. Therefore, `PopModalAsync` will not work. You need to call `PopModalAsync` when page be active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change their order when invoking `Push` and `Pop`.

In the current scene, we should better pop the current page first, then push to next page. Maybe calling them in reverse order will work in Android, however it not works in iOS. Because when invoking `OnDisappearing` method, app will miss the isntance of `PageSecond` in iOS. Therefore, `PopModalAsync` will has no effect. We can call `pop` first, and then call `push` method to make it works.

For example, in the **PageSecond.cs**:

```
public partial class PageSecond : ContentPage
{
    public PageSecond()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
    }

    protected override async void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new PageThird());
    }
}
```

The needed effect will show in iOS:

[image]

And effect in android:

[image]

Comment: I tried this but, problem didn't solved. Now third page gets pushed but when we press back from third page , second page is still there

Comment: @Anand Okey, what is the version of Xamrin Forms used in project?

Comment: @Jiang, Iam using xamarin.forms 4.7.0.1351

Comment: @Anand Okey, I used `4.8.0.1451` and in iOS 14, it works. Mayeb you can update to the latest version to have a try.

Comment: @Jiang, I updated the xamarin.forms and issue still persist

Comment: @Jiang what will be the issue? :(

Comment: @Anand You colud share the current code of second page and third page about navigation in question, I will check that.

Comment: @Jiang..Sorry It was my mistake...It worked perfect..Thanks....Will it applicable on android too?

Comment: @Anand That's great! Yes, it also works in Android. You can check that.